# Summing up list of dictionaries based on a condition and deleting few keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a  list of dictionaries with dynamic keys(keys are generated from code) as follows:

```
l=[{"key1":1,"author":"test","year":"2011"},{"key2":5,"author":"test","year":"2012"},
{"key1":3,"author":"test1","year":"2012"},
{"key1":1,"author":"test","year":"2012"}]
```

Now I want to  add up the first key values if the keys are same and group them finally.So,my final list should look like this:

```
l=[{"key1":2,"author":"test","year":["2011","2012"]},{"key2":5,"author":"test","year":"2012"},{"key1":3,"author":"test1","year":"2012"}]
```

I have tried pandas groupby but I can't use it because the keys are auto-generated.However,the code is as follows:

```
(pd.DataFrame(l)
   .groupby(['author', 'year'], as_index=False)
   .key1.sum()
   .to_dict('r'))
```

What could be a better approach?
Rules:

1. Sum up two values if the first key in dictionary is same and also the other keys author and year remain same
2. If author is not same,then don't add them up
3. If author is same but years are different,then group the years up
   and
   add the key

Comment: from your example (not the pandas code, which seems different), it seems that you want to group by a tuple: `(k, author)` where `k` is a key whose name matches `r'key\d+'` and `author` is the value of `d['author']` for a given element `d` of your list. That seems quite convoluted. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "dynamic keys". Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @PierreD Key1 is just one example I have given,it can be anything like cat or start and many more keys.The point is similar keys in dctionary with the same other keys(author,year) must be summed up.By dynamic keys,I mean keys which are generated dynamically

Comment: can you please provide a minimal piece of code that demonstrates what you mean? A `dict` can only have hashable keys, which means they have been computed by that point in your code and are (hopefully) immutable by then.

Comment: @PierreD I have a list which will be acting as a first key in dictionary.The authors and year remain the same,but the first key keeps changing based on the value given by user.

Comment: so, what makes `'key1'`, `'key2'`, ... special? The fact that they are not in `{'author', 'year'}` or the fact that they are the first key (by insertion order) of the dicts?

Comment: @PierreD The fact that they are first key in a dict.also they are not in author or year

Comment: then please see my answer for how to make the structure easier to analyze, either with or without pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `groupby-agg` on the result of `.groupby(['author', 'year']`. Aggregation is applied to each key except `author` and `year` in separate steps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df_gp = df.groupby(['author', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()

def agg_key(df, key):
    return df[df[key] != 0].groupby("author", as_index=False).agg({
        # collect the years
        "year": lambda sr: [str(el) for el in sr],
        # sum the key
        key: "sum",
    }).to_dict(orient="records")

# keys except group and author
keys = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(["author", "year"])]

# apply aggregation and flatten list of lists
ans = [el for key in keys for el in agg_key(df_gp, key)]
```

### Output

```
print(ans)

[{'author': 'test', 'year': ['2011', '2012'], 'key1': 2.0},
 {'author': 'test1', 'year': ['2012'], 'key1': 3.0},
 {'author': 'test', 'year': ['2012'], 'key2': 5.0}]
```

A single "year" is returned as a single-elemented `list` instead of a `str` for the sake of type consistency (recommended).

Comment: I cannot harcode key1 and key2 because they keep changing and there could be more keys also like key3 and key4.Also what I have is a list of dictionaries not a dataframe

Comment: I have a list of values which change based on the user value.Everytime user enters a value, a new list is generated and the items in list becomes keys and value is the term frequency of the key.Hence my keys are not fixed

Comment: That is not an implementable rule. For implementation, I need to know: **which keys are to be summed, and which keys are not**? Please provide a clear rule. For instance: "every key should be summed except author and year".

Comment: yes every key should be summed except author and year but if author and year are different for same key,they must be grouped in a list.I edited the question

Comment: Is there any possibility that we could add 0 in the list of years if there are no value.For example if I have range of years from [2001,2002,2004,2006] in the total list and if one of the year is not present,can we add a zero.for example, for the first item "year":[2001,0,0,2006].This is just my extension to question

Comment: You may try something like [`df.pivot(columns="year")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to create all year columns required. Since the focus is now quite different, you may post another separate question if you couldn't make it work. Success!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112914/adding-to-zeros-to-list-in-a-dictionary-in-a-list . This is also a question

Comment: this is wasteful and is potentially going to blow up your memory, as `df` contains one column for **each different key id**. So if there are `m` dicts in `l`, and a combined `n` values for `key1`, `key2`, etc. and `k` other keys (in the example, `k == 2` for `author` and `year`, then your `df.shape` will be `(m, n + k)`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off with a cleaner data structure, where there is nothing special with the first mapping of your dicts, and where that first mapping is split into e.g. `'key':first_mapping_key` and `'count':first_mapping_value`.

One way to do that from your list of dicts structure (where "the first key is special") is:

```
def transform(d):
    (k, v), *t = d.items()
    return dict(key=k, count=v, **dict(t))

lmod = [transform(d) for d in l]
lmod
# out:
[{'key': 'key1', 'count': 0, 'author': 'test', 'year': '2010'},
 {'key': 'key1', 'count': 1, 'author': 'test', 'year': '2011'},
 {'key': 'key2', 'count': 5, 'author': 'test', 'year': '2012'},
 {'key': 'key1', 'count': 3, 'author': 'test1', 'year': '2012'},
 {'key': 'key1', 'count': 1, 'author': 'test', 'year': '2012'}]
```

Now you can easily groupby and aggregate to your heart's content. For example:

```
(pd.DataFrame(lmod)
 .query('count != 0')
 .groupby(['key', 'author'])
 .agg({'count': sum, 'year': set})
)
```

The second topic is how to group by and aggregate without using pandas. Here is a way to do that using first principles (with only core library functions):

```
def grp_key(d):
    return d['key'], d['author']

def expect_single(a):
    values = set(a)
    assert len(values) == 1
    return next(iter(values))

_funcdict = {
    'key': expect_single,
    'author': expect_single,
    'count': sum,
}
def agg(lod):
    keys = {k: 1 for d in lod for k in d}  # insertion-order union of all keys
    d = {k: _funcdict.get(k, set)(d.get(k) for d in lod) for k in keys}
    return d
```

Application:

```
out = [
    agg(list(g))
    for k, g in groupby(sorted([
        d for d in lmod if d['count'] != 0
    ], key=grp_key), key=grp_key)
]
out
# output:
[{'key': 'key1', 'count': 2, 'author': 'test', 'year': {'2011', '2012'}},
 {'key': 'key1', 'count': 3, 'author': 'test1', 'year': {'2012'}},
 {'key': 'key2', 'count': 5, 'author': 'test', 'year': {'2012'}}]
```